# Hystrix no open circuit when 404

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, feign

I am making requests with FeignClient from one Springboot microservice to another to get a resource. When requests are made for resources that do not exist, a 404 not found is returned.

The problem comes when many requests are made, Hystrix understands that there is a failure and opens the circuit, so that all requests return 404.

How can I configure Hystrix so that it does not open the circuit for specific error codes? Thanks!